# Why does google visit my url every time I start chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I've noticed that Google keeps visiting some of my url:s each time i boot up Google Chrome, does anyone know why this might be?

This wouldn't be much of a problem, except that it keeps hitting an login-url for a system I've built. And each time there's an unknown login-call I receive a text message... so, it's kind of annoying.

The IP range i keep receiving this visits from is  66.102.9.*.

Sure, I could block this ip-range. But first I'd like to know why I keep receiving this visits. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you use Google Chrome, it sends GET requests to Google's servers for the bowser's update checks and for the Chrome apps updates.

Chrome sends requests to multiple URLs when it’s checking for and downloading updates. The order of requests is determined dynamically at runtime. Both HTTP and HTTPS protocols might be tried. The following URL list of hostnames and paths can change at any time without notice:

- www.google.com/dl/*
- *.gvt1.com
- tools.google.com/service/update2
- dl.google.com/*
- google.com/dl/*
- clients2.google.com
- update.googleapis.com/service/update2

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is your Chrome's starting page and you could change it in the settings.

That's where I'd start, unless you have already checked that.

If that's not it, try the Google Chrome forums